# What is the exact meaning of ZooKeeper Avg Request Latency?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, metrics

I'm looking into ZooKeeper metrics to monitor better our servers, but I can't find any super clear explanation about some values:
What Avg and Max Request Latency exactly mean? What does it include?

Does it include the time since it gets into the Outstanding queue until the response is returned?

I found the list of metrics here:

- https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-monitor-zookeeper/
- https://signalfx.com/zookeeper-monitoring/

Answer (score 1):

1. **outstanding_requests   Number** - of requests queued
   Resource: Saturation   Four-letter words, AdminServer, JMX
2. **avg_latency** - Amount of time it takes to respond to a client request (in ms) Work: Throughput    Four-letter words, AdminServer, JMX
3. **num_alive_connections** - Number of clients connected to ZooKeeper Resource: Availability  Four-letter words, AdminServer, JMX
4. **followers** - Number of active followers   Resource: Availability  Four-letter words, AdminServer
5. **pending_syncs** - Number of pending syncs from followers   Other   Four-letter words, AdminServer, JMX
6. **open_file_descriptor_count** - Number of file descriptors in use   Resource: Utilization   Four-letter words, AdminServer